# Start only specific systemd service from list of services using Ansible

Tags: ansible, systemd

I have list of `systemd` services defined as

```
vars:
  systemd_scripts: ['a.service', 'b.service', 'c.service']
```

Now I want to stop only `a.service` from above list. How this can be achieved using [`systemd`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/systemd_module.html)_module?

Comment: When you say `only a.service` do you mean `the first service in the list` ? Moreover, what have you tried so far and what is the exact problem you have ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is very vague and unspecific. However, parts of your question could be answered with the following approach

```yaml
- name: Loop over service list and stop one service
  systemd:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    state: stopped
  when:
    - systemd_scripts[item] == 'a.service'
  with_items: "{{ systemd_scripts }}"
```

You may need to extend and change it for your needs and required functionality.

Regarding discovering, starting and stopping services via Ansible facts ([`service_facts`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/service_facts_module.html)) and `systemd` you may have a look into

**Further readings**

- [Ansible: How to get disabled but running services?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70376280/6771046)
- [How to declare a variable for `service_facts`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69476972/6771046)?
- [How to check service exists and is not installed in the server using `service_facts` module in an Ansible playbook?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69773111/6771046)

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to achieve? As written, you could just do:

```
- name: Stop service A
  systemd:
    name: a.service
    state: stopped
```

If instead you mean "the first service", use the `first` filter or an index:

```
- name: Stop first service
  systemd:
    name: "{{ systemd_scripts | first }}"
    state: stopped
```

OR

```
- name: Stop first service
  systemd:
    name: "{{ systemd_scripts[0] }}"
    state: stopped
```