# Ansible: Playbook to export systemd status into CSV format

Tags: linux, csv, ansible, centos, systemd

We have more than 1000+ VMs running on different Hyper-V nodes. I want to create a report in CSV format for one systemd service status.

For example, I would like to check the running status of `postfix` whether it's in state `started` or `stopped`. These statuses need to be print into CSV file format.

Expected result as below format

[image]

Comment: Cool. What did you try so far? What happened?

Comment: Does [Ansible: How to get ... services?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70376280/6771046), [How to check service exists ...?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69773111/6771046) or [... specific systemd service from list of services using Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70590709/6771046) gives an idea where to start?

Comment: @U880D Thanks I have already gone through the Ansible documents regarding gather facts. But I am not able to export the status to CSV format. Do u have any idea how to play with Ansible ?

Comment: https://gregsowell.com/?p=7289
Found some cool stuff with these I did some alternative then I got above output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I got solution for this above request.
Here is the code below, helpful for others.

**`main.yml`**

```yaml
---
- name: Generate an HTML report from Jinja2 template
  hosts: postfix-hosts
  gather_facts: true

  vars:

    #email settings
    email_subject: System status Report
    email_host: stackoverflw.smtp.com
    email_from: noreply@stackoverflw.com
    email_to: AdMin_Stack@stackoverflw.com

    #random settings
    csv_path: /tmp
    csv_filename: report.csv
    headers: Hostname,OS,Distro Ver,Kernel Ver,Postfix Status,FQDN,Total VCPU,Total RAM,Total SWAP,Total Disk,Hyper-V

  tasks:

  - name: Gather last Postfix Status
    ansible.builtin.shell:  systemctl status postfix | egrep -i Active | awk '{ print $2,$3}'
    register: active

  - name: Save CSV headers
    ansible.builtin.lineinfile:
      dest: "{{ csv_path }}/{{ csv_filename }}"
      line: "{{ headers }}"
      create: true
      state: present
    delegate_to: localhost
    run_once: true

  - name: Build out CSV file
    ansible.builtin.lineinfile:
      dest: "{{ csv_path }}/{{ csv_filename }}"
      line: "{{ inventory_hostname }},{{ ansible_distribution }},{{ ansible_distribution_version }},{{ ansible_kernel }},{{ active.stdout }},{{ ansible_fqdn }},{{ ansible_processor_vcpus }},{{ ansible_memtotal_mb }},{{ ansible_swaptotal_mb }},{{ ansible_devices.vda.partitions.vda1.size }},{{ ansible_product_name }}"
      create: true
      state: present
    delegate_to: localhost

  - name: Read in CSV to variable
    community.general.read_csv:
      path: "{{ csv_path }}/{{ csv_filename }}"
    register: csv_file
    delegate_to: localhost
    run_once: true

  - name: Send Email
    community.general.mail:
      host: "{{ email_host }}"
      from: "{{ email_from }}"
      port: 25
      to: "{{ email_to }}"
      subject: "[Ansible] {{ email_subject }}"
      body: "{{ lookup('template', 'report.html.j2') }}"
      attach: "{{ csv_path }}/{{ csv_filename }}"
      subtype: html
    delegate_to: localhost
    run_once: true
```

**`report.html.j2`**

```html
<table style="border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse;">
<tr>
    {% for header in headers.split(",") %}
    <th style="border: 1px solid black; padding: 8px 16px;">{{ header }}</th>
    {% endfor %}
</tr>
{% for host in csv_file.list %}
<tr>
    {% for header in headers.split(",") %}
    <td style="border: 1px solid black; padding: 8px 16px;">{{ host[header] }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Thanks to the [gregsowell blog](https://gregsowell.com/?p=7289) helped me get these done.