# How to check `uptime` of Remote Server thru Ansible and send report as CSV and HTML via mail?

Tags: linux, ansible, uptime

I have created an Ansbile script to check `uptime` of Remote Servers (nearly 60+ servers in a inventory group `linux`) and to send it to email with CSV and HTML file. It's working but its sending seperate mail for each server.

I need it to gather the output and send a single mail with all server uptime and hostname in csv and HTML.

Here is my script.

**`main.yaml`**

```yaml
---
- name: Generate Uptime HTML Report and Send Email
  hosts: linux
  gather_facts: true

  vars:

    email_subject: Uptime Report
    email_host: xyz
    email_from: xyz
    email_to: xyz
    email_body_template: templates/report.html.j2
    csv_path: /tmp
    csv_filename: report.csv
    headers: Hostname,Uptime_In_Days

  tasks:

    - name: Get Uptime
      command: uptime
      register: uptime_result

    - name: Extract Uptime in Days
      set_fact:
        uptime_days: "{{ uptime_result.stdout | regex_replace('^.*up ([0-9]+) day.*', '\\1') | int }}"
      when: uptime_result.rc == 0

    - name: Create CSV Data
      set_fact:
        csv_data:
          - Hostname: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
            Uptime_In_Days: "{{ uptime_days }}"
      when: uptime_result.rc == 0

    - name: Transfer CSV Data File
      copy:
        content: "{{ csv_data | to_nice_json }}"
        dest: "{{ csv_path }}/{{ csv_filename }}"
        mode: '0644'

    - name: Send Email
      mail:
        host: "{{ email_host }}"
        from: "{{ email_from }}"
        to: "{{ email_to }}"
        subject: "[Ansible] {{ email_subject }}"
        body: "{{ lookup('template', email_body_template) }}"
        attach: "{{ csv_path }}/{{ csv_filename }}"
        subtype: html
```

**`html.j2`**

```html
<sub><table style="border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse;">
<tr>
    {% for header in headers.split(",") %}
    <th style="border: 1px solid black; padding: 8px 16px;">{{ header }}</th>
    {% endfor %}
</tr>
{% for host in csv_data %}
<tr>
    {% for header in headers.split(",") %}
    <td style="border: 1px solid black; padding: 8px 16px;">{{ host[header] }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table></sub>
```

Answer (score 2):

Take the attribute *uptime_seconds* from *ansible_facts* and set the variable *uptime* in days

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        uptime: "{{ (ansible_facts.uptime_seconds/86400)|round(2) }}"
```

Declare the dictionary

```yaml
  host_uptime: "{{ dict(ansible_play_hosts|
                        zip(ansible_play_hosts|
                            map('extract', hostvars, 'uptime'))) }}"
```

gives, for example

```yaml
  host_uptime:
    test_11: '0.52'
    test_13: '0.52'
```

Create the templates. Fit the formats to your needs

```html
shell> cat templates/report.html.j2
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Report hosts uptime</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
{% for header in headers.split(',') %}
        <th>{{ header }}</th>
{% endfor %}
      </tr>
{% for host in ansible_play_hosts %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{ host }}</td><td>{{ host_uptime[host] }}</td>
      </tr>
{% endfor %}
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

```bash
shell> cat templates/report.csv.j2
{{ headers }}
{% for host,uptime in host_uptime.items() %}
{{ host }},{{ uptime }}
{% endfor %}
```

Test the HTML template

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ lookup('template', 'report.html.j2') }}"
```

gives

```html
  msg: |-
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <title>Report hosts uptime</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>Host</th>
            <th>Uptime_In_Days</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>test_11</td><td>0.52</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>test_13</td><td>0.52</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Test the CSV template

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ lookup('template', 'report.csv.j2') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: |-
    Host,Uptime_In_Days
    test_11,0.52
    test_13,0.52
```

Write the file on the localhost

```yaml
    - template:
        src: report.csv.j2
        dest: /tmp/report.csv
        mode: 0644
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true
```

gives

```bash
shell> cat /tmp/report.csv 
Host,Uptime_In_Days
test_11,0.52
test_13,0.52
```

Send the email

```yaml
   - mail:
        host: localhost
        from: "{{ ansible_user }}"
        to: root
        subject: '[Ansible] Report uptime'
        body: "{{ lookup('template', 'report.html.j2') }}"
        subtype: html
        attach: /tmp/report.csv
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true
```

gives (where the email client renders HTML to text)

```bash
Return-Path: <admin@example.org>
X-Original-To: root
Delivered-To: root@example.org
Received: from [127.0.0.1] (localhost [127.0.0.1])
 by example.org (Postfix) with ESMTPS id 2FCC41802F6
 for <root>; Tue, 24 Oct 2023 05:24:20 +0200 (CEST)
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; -charset="utf-8"; boundary="===============6826681646037083043=="
MIME-Version: 1.0
From: admin@example.org
Date: Tue, 24 Oct 2023 05:24:20 +0200
Subject: [Ansible] Report uptime
X-Mailer: Ansible mail module
To: root@example.org
Cc: 
Message-Id: <20231024032420.2FCC41802F6@example.org>

Report hosts uptime
Host Uptime_In_Days
test_110.52
test_130.52



[report.csv  application/octet-stream (65 bytes)]
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- name: Mail uptime table
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: true

  vars:

    headers: Host,Uptime_In_Days
    host_uptime: "{{ dict(ansible_play_hosts|
                          zip(ansible_play_hosts|
                              map('extract', hostvars, 'uptime'))) }}"
    
  tasks:

    - set_fact:
        uptime: "{{ (ansible_facts.uptime_seconds/86400)|round(2) }}"

    - block:
        
        - debug:
            var: host_uptime
        - debug:
            msg: "{{ lookup('template', 'report.html.j2') }}"
        - debug:
            msg: "{{ lookup('template', 'report.csv.j2') }}"

      when: debug|d(false)|bool
      run_once: true

    - block:

        - template:
            src: report.csv.j2
            dest: /tmp/report.csv
            mode: 0644

        - mail:
            host: localhost
            from: "{{ ansible_user }}"
            to: root
            subject: '[Ansible] Report uptime'
            body: "{{ lookup('template', 'report.html.j2') }}"
            subtype: html
            attach: /tmp/report.csv
          when: mail_enable|d(false)|bool

      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true
```

Answer (score 1):

> ***How to gather `uptime` on Linux Remote Nodes?***

Since you are already  `gather_facts` in order to have [Ansible facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#ansible-facts) avaibale, it also contain `ansible_uptime_seconds`. See the minimal reproducible example

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: true

  tasks:

  - debug:
      msg: "Days up: {{ (ansible_facts.uptime_seconds / 86400) | int }}"
```

There is no need for `command` and `set_fact`.

> ***It's working but its ... for each server.***

A CSV report can therefore directly be written on the Control Node for all hosts in the current play.

```yaml
---
- hosts: linux
  become: false
  gather_facts: true

  vars:

    csv_path: '.'
    csv_filename: 'report.csv'

  tasks:

  - name: Write uptime into CSV
    delegate_to: localhost # aka Control Node
    lineinfile:
      dest: "{{ csv_path }}/{{ csv_filename }}"
      line: "{{ inventory_hostname }},{{ (ansible_facts.uptime_seconds / 86400) | int }}"
      create: true
      state: present
    loop: "{{ ansible_play_hosts }}"
```

For **How to proceed further?** you may have a look into

**Similar Q&A**

- [Ansible: Playbook to export `systemd` status into CSV format](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73740026/6771046)